# Dynamic component inside a component that is rendered with render() function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

I saw in the docs that you can have a dynamic component inside your VueComponent like this :

```
<component :is="componentName" v-bind="componentProps" @custom-event="doSomething" />
```

I am trying to have one of these dynamic components inside a dynamically rendered component (with the `render()` function, not with an HTML template). Without too much hope, I've tried this :

```
render(createElement: CreateElement) {
  return createElement('component', props: {
    'is': 'TestComponent'
  });
}
```

but I got

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <component> - did you register the component correctly?
```

So again, not hoping too much for a miracle, I tried to import `Component` and declare it as a component :

```
@Component({
  components: {
    Component,
    TestComponent
  }
})
export default class DynamicThingy extends Vue {
  render(createElement: CreateElement): VNode {
    return createElement('Component', {
      props: {
        'is': 'TestComponent'
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But then I get

```
[Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: Component
```

Any idea how that could be possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `createElement()` must be either

> - An HTML tag name,
> - component options,
> - or async function resolving to one of these.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

So in a render function, you can simply create a function* that returns one or another component's options based on your desired criteria, and let that be your first argument. *This function is identical to the function you'd write to determine what goes into the :is prop)

**You only need the dynamic component `<component />` and `:is` prop in a template** where you don't have the possibility to do it programmatically.

You can use [this smart-list component from the vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) as an example.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working except for one case : with `<component :is="cmp">` when `cmp` is an empty string, nothing is rendered there and no error is thrown, now I have to put in a component or I get an error

Comment: You could let it return `'div'` instead of an empty string in your function. It will render a single 'div' but at least it won't crash. Or, you could have the createElement function only be called when the element is truthy (like a v-if). Not quite sure how the built in 'component' handles empty strings, but with a render function you'll have to reimplement a solution yourself.